# Get all rows if it matches input data, that data is present comma separated values in a single column

Tags: sql-server

Basically, I want to get all rows matching with the input data, the input data is present in various forms i.e. single value in a column or comma seperated in another row, I want to fetch all rows which has that input value

```
        SELECT ERSBusinessLogic_ID AS 'Rule ID'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_Formula] 'Formula'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_OutputName] AS 'Output Name'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_OutputDestination] AS 'Output Destination'  
        ,REPLACE ( cosd. ERSBusinessLogic.[ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries] , ',' , ' ;' ) AS 'Commodity Series ID'  
        ,InputUnit.[ERSUnit_Desc] AS 'Input Unit'  
        ,[ERSConversionFactor_CF] AS 'Conversion Factor'  
        ,REPLACE ( [ERSBusinessLogic_MacroDesc] , 'Null' , '' ) AS 'Macro'  
        ,CONVERT(varchar(100), OutputUnit.[ERSUnit_Desc]) AS 'Output Unit'  
        ,TimeInput.[ERSTimeDimensionType_Desc] AS 'Input Time Dimension Type'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue] 'Input Time Value'  
        ,TimeOutput.[ERSTimeDimensionType_Desc] AS 'Output Time Dimension Type'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_OutputTimeDimensionValue] AS 'Output Time Value'  
        ,(SELECT [ERSGeographyType_Desc] FROM   cosd. [ERSGeographyType_LU] WHERE ERSGeographyType_ID IN(InputGeo.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID)) AS 'Input Geo Type'  
        ,REPLACE ( [ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID] , ',' , ' ,' ) AS 'Input Geo Value'  
        ,(SELECT [ERSGeographyType_Desc] FROM   cosd. [ERSGeographyType_LU] WHERE ERSGeographyType_ID IN(OutputGeo.ERSGeographyDimension_ERSGeographyType_ID)) AS 'Output Geo Type' 
        ,CONVERT(varchar(100), [ERSBusinessLogic_OutputGeographyDimensionID]) AS 'Output Geo Value'  
        ,[ERSDataPrivacy_Desc] AS 'Privacy'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_Type] AS 'Type'  
        ,[ERSBusinessLogic_LongDesc] AS 'Long Description'  
        ,REPLACE ( [ERSBusinessLogic_InputSources] , ',' , ' ;' ) AS 'Input Sources'  
        FROM cosd. ERSBusinessLogic 
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSUnit_LU] AS InputUnit ON [ERSBusinessLogic_InputUnitID] like InputUnit.[ERSUnit_ID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSConversionFactors] ON [ERSBusinessLogic_ConvFactorID] = [ERSConversionFactorID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSUnit_LU] AS OutputUnit ON [ERSBusinessLogic_OutputUnitID] = OutputUnit.[ERSUnit_ID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSTimeDimensionType_LU] AS TimeInput ON [ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionTypeID] = TimeInput.[ERSTimeDimensionType_ID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSTimeDimensionType_LU] AS TimeOutput ON [ERSBusinessLogic_OutputTimeDimensionTypeID] = TimeOutput.[ERSTimeDimensionType_ID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSDataPrivacy_LU] ON [ERSBusinessLogic_PrivacyID] = [ERSDataPrivacy_ID]  
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSGeographyDimension_LU] AS InputGeo ON [ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID] = CONVERT(varchar(100), InputGeo.ERSGeographyDimension_ID) 
        LEFT JOIN [CoSD].[ERSGeographyDimension_LU] AS OutputGeo ON [ERSBusinessLogic_OutputGeographyDimensionID] = OutputGeo.ERSGeographyDimension_ID 
        WHERE  cosd. ERSBusinessLogic .[ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries]  = '2257' OR  cosd. ERSBusinessLogic .[ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries]  like '%2257%'
```

This is how my table looks like

```
   BID     Count  formula
     1      4    1078,1079,1080,1081
     2      1         1078
```

So if the user enters 1078 then both rows are to be populated, any ideas ?

Comment: What if the user enters `1078,1080`?

Comment: the requirement of the page that I am developing will allow only one user input

Comment: In that case it's a simple WHERE ... LIKE ... clause.

Comment: yup it worked. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, evaluate the possibility of creating a new table to keep atomic values in your columns to comply with [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). That would give you a performance improvement when querying the data.
If the previous is not possible, you can make a condition like the following:

```
WHERE ',' + formula + ',' LIKE '%,' + @YourParameter + ',%'
```

Note that this will need to read the entire table as no indexing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
...WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + @UserInput + ',', ',' + formula + ',') <> 0 ...
```